# Removing the last two instances of a character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a string based on selected checkboxes. I wrote a statement that will add pluralization if there are multiple strings selected, but I cannot figure out how to remove the last two commas that are put into the 'policyHidden' field by the array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').change(function() {

      var keys = [];

      var policies = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).siblings('span').text(); }).get();

      $.each(policies, function(key, value) { keys.push(value) });

      output = keys.join(", ");

      FormSetFieldValue('policyHidden', output);

      if (keys.length > 1) {
        keys.splice(keys.length - 1, 0, "and");
      }

      FormSetFieldValue('policyHidden', output);

    });
});
```

example output is

```
value1, value2, and, value3
```

I just want to remove the last two commas. should I do a regex?

*FYI, FormSetFieldValue is a function from another script; first variable calls the variable wanting to be changed, second one is the set value. Shouldn't have any consequence on the problem at hand.*

Comment: You should keep the Oxford comma

Comment: @tandu - He shouldn't. It looks horrible.

Comment: @tandu this was borne of a client request, but I agree with Joseph on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think putting it in there - and then removing it - is counter-intuitive.
You shouldn't put it into your string that way in the first place:

```
var output = [];
output[1] = keys.pop();
output[0] = keys.join(', ');

output = output.join(' and ');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfKjp/

Comment: much more elegant than mine. yup, mine was put together as "beginner programmer on a timecrunch". Thanks!

Comment: @silentpost - Actually, coming to think of it; if we're already using `.pop()`, we don't need `.slice()`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

regex is a one option.  you can also do a javascript replace function for ', and,' with ' and'

```
var str = "value1, value2, and, value3"
str.replace(', and,',' and')
```

you may have to escape the commas.